# Clarification about Sean Parent's talk "Inheritance is the base class of evil"

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, factory, type-erasure

Sean Parent's talk, [Inheritance is the base class of evil](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil), says that polymorphism is not a property of the type, but rather a property of how it is used. As a thumb rule, don't use inheritance to implement interfaces. Among the many benefits of this is the devirtualization of classes which have virtual functions only because they were implementing an interface. Here's an example :

```
class Drawable
{
public:
virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class DrawA : public Drawable
{
public:
void draw() override{//do something}
};

class UseDrawable
{
public:
void do(){mDraw->draw();}
Drawable* mDraw;
};
```

Here, instead of `UseDrawable` requiring `mDraw` to be a `Drawable*`, you could have it use a type-erased class which can wrap around any class implementing a member called `draw`. So, something like a `boost::type_erasure::any` with the appropriate definition. That way, `DrawA` doesn't need to inherit from `Drawable` - the polymorphism was really `UseDrawable`s requirement and not really a property of `DrawA`.

I am trying to refactor some code following this principle. I have an abstract class `ModelInterface` and two concrete classes `ModelA` and `ModelB` inheriting from `ModelInterface`. Following Sean's advice, it makes sense not to force `ModelA` and `ModelB` into the inheritance hierarchy and simply use type-erasure at locations which require a class satisfying the concept modelled by `ModelInterface`.

Now, my problem is that most places in my code which currently use a `ModelInterface` also do so by constructing an appropriate object based on a runtime configuration file. Currently, the factory would `new` an appropriate object and return a `ModelInterface*`. If I refactor the code to use a type-erased concept(say something like `boost::type_erasure::any<implement ModelInterface>`) at these locations in code, how do I construct such objects at runtime? Will `ModelA` and `ModelB` still need to be RTTI-enabled classes? Or can I factory-construct and use them without RTTI info somehow?

(With RTTI, I can have an abstract class, say `FactoryConstructible`, and use `dynamic_cast<void*>` to get the final type.)

Comment: I apologize for the long-winded question. Could the close-voter ask for a clarification please?

Comment: I think that perhaps, there is an instinct, that if your question does not have a clear code sample...but seems philosophical and links to someone's talk...that it is suspect.  Can you reformulate this question so that I don't have to click on a link and watch a talk to understand it?  Narrow and focus the question.  The trend here is "lots of people with lots of things to talk about" hence needing to get directed and ask questioners to be very specific.

Comment: _"Could the close-voter ask for a clarification please?"_ Of course. Your question tend's to being either _'too broad'_, or _'opinion based'_.

Comment: @HostileFork Makes sense. Let me try to do add a code sample illustrating the points I am referring to. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, `boost::any` is inappropriate for this purpose (at least, as an interface). I think you should return some `Model` from your factory, which stores some type-erased object fulfilling the ModelInterface concept. The `Model` then is similar to the `Document` Sean Parent uses (though it does not store a collection but a single object).

Comment: *"how do I construct such objects at runtime"* Well, just like any factory creates objects with different types at runtime. The difference is, you wrap that object in a `Model` object and return the `Model` object by value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Type erasure 101:

Step 1: make a regular (or semi-regular move-only) type that hides the detail.

```
struct exposed_type;
```

This class exposes the concepts you want to support.  Copy, move, destroy, equals, total order, hash, and/or whatever custom concepts you need to support.

```
struct exposed_type {
  exposed_type(exposed_type const&);
  exposed_type(exposed_type&&);
  friend bool operator<(exposed_type const&, exposed_type const&);
  friend std::size_t hash(exposed_type const&);
  // etc
};
```

Many of these concepts can be roughly mapped from a pure virtual interface method in your current inheritance based solution.

Create non-virtual methods in your Regular type that expresses the concepts.  Copy/assign for copy, etc.

Step 2: Write a type erasure helper.

```
struct internal_interface;
```

Here you have pure virtual interfaces.  `clone()` for copy,etc.

```
struct internal_interface {
  virtual ~internal_interface() {}
  virtual internal_interface* clone() const = 0;
  virtual int cmp( internal_interface const& o ) const = 0;
  virtual std::size_t get_hash() const = 0;
  // etc
  virtual std::type_info const* my_type_info() const = 0;
};
```

Store a smart pointer<sup>1</sup> to this in your Regular type above.

```
struct exposed_type {
  std::unique_ptr<internal_interface> upImpl;
```

Forward the regular methods to the helper.  For example:

```
exposed_type::exposed_type( exposed_type const& o ):
  upImpl( o.upImpl?o.upImpl->clone():nullptr )
{}
exposed_type::exposed_type( exposed_type&& o )=default;
```

Step 3: write a type erasure implementation.  This is a `template` class that stores a `T` and inherits from the helper, and forwards the interface to the `T`.  Use free functions (sort of like `std::begin`) that uses methods in the default implementation if no adl free function was found.

```
// used if ADL does not find a hash:
template<class T>
std::size_t hash( T const& t ) {
  return std::hash<T>{}(t);
}
template<class T>
struct internal_impl:internal_interface {
  T t;
  virtual ~internal_impl() {}
  virtual internal_impl* clone() const {
    return new internal_impl{t};
  }
  virtual int cmp( internal_interface const& o ) const {
    if (auto* po = dynamic_cast<internal_interface const*>(&o))
    {
      if (t < *po) return -1;
      if (*po < t) return 1;
      return 0;
    }
    if (my_type_info()->before(*o.my_type_info()) return -1;
    if (o.my_type_info()->before(*my_type_info()) return 1;
    ASSERT(FALSE);
    return 0;
  }
  virtual std::size_t get_hash() const {
    return hash(t);
  }
  // etc
  std::type_info const* my_type_info() const {
    return std::addressof( typeid(T) ); // note, static type, not dynamic
  }
};
```

Step 4: add a constructor to your regular type that takes a `T` and constructs a type erasure implementation from it, and stuffs that in its smart pointer to the helper.

```
template<class T,
  // SFINAE block using this ctor as a copy/move ctor:
  std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<exposed_type, std::decay_t<T>>::value, int>* =nullptr
>
exposed_type( T&& t ):
  upImpl( new internal_impl<std::decay_t<T>>{std::forward<T>(t)} )
{}
```

After all this work, you now have non-intrusive polymorphic system with a regular (or semi-regular) value type.

Your factory functions return the regular type.

Look into sample implementations of `std::function` to see this done fully.

---

<sup>1</sup> both unique and shared are good choices, depending on if you want to store immutable/copy on write data, or manually clone.

Comment: *"add a constructor to your regular type that takes a `T`"* It might be useful to provide a free function `template<class T, class... Args> Wrapper emplace_wrap(Args&&...);` such that the type can be emplaced in the type erasure implementation class without move/copy.

Comment: @dyp That, and an `emplace` tag you can pass to a constructor.  But that is covered in type erasure 102: this time its forwarding.

Comment: Where can I read more about these techniques, the mentioned things like emplace, perfect forwarding and type erasure 102 etc.

Comment: @meguli I had written a bunch on SO Documentation, but SO Documentation was taken down.