# best way to inherit from a class without virtual functions

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I am trying to implement some event handling.
There are different types of events: integerChangedEvent, boolChangedEvent, stringChangedEvent and so on...
Each of these events hold some of the same information like: std::string settingsName, std::string containerName...
But also each of these different event types also hold some information which are unique for this event types: e.g. int double std::string... newValue and oldValue.

My idea to not copy the same code thousands of times is to make a base class called SettingsEvent.
This class should hold the information which all event types also would hold and which are same (see above "settingsName, containerName") and of cause the setter and getter of these information.

All other events can inherit this base class and add their own members / methods.

so far, everything is fine.

But C++ (11) does allow me to inherit from a class without virtual methods, but it does not allow me to dynamic_cast from the base to the derived class, when not at least one method is defined as virtual.
But I don't want to allow, that any of these methods are overwrite able.
What can I do? Is there a specifier which allows me to cast a non-virtual class?

for better understanding, here is some piece of code:

```
class SettingsEvent
{
public:
    std::string getSettingsName() const;
    std::string getSettingsContainerName() const;
    // some more methods I don't want to write down know... ;)
protected:
    SettingsEvent(); //protected constructor, to ensure nobody creates an object of this base class
private:
    std::string m_settingsName;
    std::string m_settingsContainerName;
    // some more members I also don't want to write down know...
};

class IntegerChangedEvent : public SettingsEvent
{
public:
    IntegerChangedEvent(); //public constructor, it is allowed to create an object of this class
    int getNewValue() const;
    int getOldValue() const;
    //also here are more methods I don't want to list
private:
    int m_newValue;
    int m_oldValue;
    //also more members I don't want to list
};
```

On another part in my code I want to pass the event to a method. In that method I want to cast it into the IntegerChangedEvent:

```
void handleEvent(SettingsEvent* event)
{
    //to be honest, the event itself knows what kind of event it is (enum) but lets say it is an IntegerChangedEvent to keep it simple
    IntegerChangedEvent* intEvent = dynamic_cast<IntegerChangedEvent*>(event);
   
    if(intEvent)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

the error message is: "C2683: 'dynamic_cast': 'SettingsEvent' is not a polymorphic type

Comment: *"But C++ (11) does not allow me to inherit from a class without at least one method which is virtual."* That's not right, where did you get this from?

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the rule that you need a `virtual` member to enable polymorphism. But you can inherit without polymorphism.

Comment: from my compiler... "C2683: 'dynamic_cast': 'SettingsEvent' is not a polymorphic type"

Comment: so without a virtual method I am not allowed to dynamic_cast into the correct "super class" ?

Comment: Can you modify your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux what else can I do to convert from SettingsEvent to IntegerChangedEvent?

Comment: @JorgeBellon sure give me a sec

Comment: You can make the destructor `virtual` to enable polymorphism if no other member can be `virtual`.

Comment: What is your objection to virtual members?  Why not simply have a virtual destructor in your base class?

Comment: If you know that `SettingsEvent` reference/pointer is a `IntegerChangedEvent`, you can use `static_cast<IntegerChangedEvent*>(ptr)` to cast it to your derived type. Casting from derived to base type also works.
For dynamic cast you will need runtime type information. If you don't declare any member function as virtual (destructor is enough), then you won't likely be able to do that.

Comment: @ all: what do you guys think is the better way? setting the destructor to virtual so that dynamic_cast is working? or use static_cast? The "problem" is: that other persons in my team also need to convert the event, because it is used multiple times. And to cast in a static way to a "super class" is new to me

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you! I'll change the destructor to virtual. But now I know whats the problem =)

Comment: RTTI information usually isn't included unless that class has a form of [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) generated for it by the compiler. Without that metadata, the class is just a "plain data" that doesn't really "know" anything about itself. Compiler knew that when compiling the code, but the runtime object doesn't. That's why dynamic cast didn't work.

Comment: It may seem a missing feature in the language - there's no other way to tell the compiler to generate that metadata without marking something as virtual. But note that when you want some runtime-polymorphic behavior, then you actually do need virtual methods - at least for a proper cleanup - imagine a list/vector/smartptr<YourBaseClass>. If YourBaseClass has only a plain destructor, then destruction of any such things would destroy the contents as-if-were-base only. Even simple std::string held in a derived class would be a memory leak. Hence: virtual destructor. Hence: no problems with RTTI.

Comment: Instead of using polymorphism (which is intrusive), you could use runtime polymorphic objects — using polymorphic container wrappers as an internal interface around the non-polymorphic event objects.  q.v. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26199467/4641116) or Sean Parent's 24 minute presentation [Inheritance is The Base Class of Evil](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so the event knows what type it is.

```
 switch (event->type)
 {
   case IntegerChangedEventType: {
       IntegerChangedEvent* ievent = static_cast<IntegerChangedEventType*>(event);
       handleIntegerChangedEvent(ievent);
       break;
   }
   case StringChangedEventType: {
       StringChangedEvent* sevent = static_cast<StringChangedEventType*>(event);
       handleStringChangedEvent(sevent);
       break;
   }
   // ... etc etc etc
 }
```

(You can use either static or dynamic cast; dynamic cast obviously requires at least one virtual function; static cast is perfectly OK if you are sure events don't lie about their types).

Congratulations to us! We've just reimplemented virtual function dispatch, *poorly*, but we did it *all by ourselves* without listening to all those pesky OO pseudo-gurus, and we can proud ourselves on this tremendous achievement! Virtual bad, non-virtual good!

We could have written

```
event->handle();
```

and call it a day, but where's the fun in that?

OK you say, but the event doesn't really know how to handle itself. It's just a little dumb collection of values. So `event->handle();` is not feasible. In order to implement it, we would have to bring in all kinds of application business logic, possibly creating circular dependency hell. What now?

Enter [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It's a design pattern invented specifically to handle this situation. It decouples virtual dispatch mechanism from the actual logic to be called via this mechanism. The virtual dispatch is the responsibility of the `SettingsEvent` class. The logic is the responsibility of the `EventVisitor` class. So `EventVisitor` knows *how* to handle various events, and `SettingsEvent` tells it *what* to handle right now. The overall flow is not much different from our initial switch-case code, and the boilerplate is nor even reduced, but the code is more structured and easy to modify. There's no way you add a new event type and forget to update old handlers. The compiler will yell at ya.

```
 class EventVisitor
 {
    virtual void handle(IntegerChangedEvent& ev) = 0;
    virtual void handle(StringChangedEvent& ev) = 0;
 };

 class SettingsEvent 
 {
   virtual void accept (EventVisitor& vis) = 0;
 };

 class IntegerChangedEvent: public SettingsEvent
 {
   void accept (EventVisitor& vis) override { vis.handle(*this); }
 };

 class StringChangedEvent: public SettingsEvent
 {
   void accept (EventVisitor& vis) override { vis.handle(*this); }
 };

 // actual event handling logic
 class AppEventHandler : public EventVisitor
 {
   void handle(IntegerChangedEvent& ev) override { /* specific logic */ }
   void handle(StringChangedEvent& ev) override { /* specific logic */ }
 };
```

OK you say, but the visitor is a couple decades old, don't we have something more modern, lean, mean, hipster-friendly, and not reeking of 1990s over a 15 mile radius? Sure we do! C++17 brings us [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), which is basically the same as the visitor pattern of old, only the *what* part is handled by `std::variant` itself and not by any `Event` it holds. You put all your `SettingsEvent` subclasses inside a `variant`, and it knows what to do next. No virtual anything needed.

```
using AnyEvent = std::variant<IntegerChangedEvent, StringChangedEvent, ...>;

AnyEvent event = ...;
std::visit(overloaded 
           {
             [](IntegerChangedEvent& ev) { ... },
             [](StringChangedEvent& ev) { ... },
           }, event);
```

So here we are, having made a full circle, from the prehistoric Fortran-style dispatch on types through basic OO through advanced OO and back to Fortran-style, but now with a lot more style. Choose whichever you like.

Comment: Here's hoping `overloaded` gets standardised soon, but those wanting to use it for now can get an example implementation from [that cppreference `std::visit` link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) or from various articles etc about it.

Comment: sounds interesting... let me think about that. So the last part is c++17 but we are using c++11, so we can't use that. But the Visitor pattern looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're inheriting a class, you should have virtual destructors to create a vtable, which would then allow a dynamic cast.

In the spirit of "prefer containment to inheritance", why not simply contain `SettingsEvent` in your `IntegerChangedEvent`?  Also in the spirit of "use inheritance to make similar things behave differently" and "use templates to do the same thing with different types" could you not use a templated `ChangedEvent` class?

Take a look at this example:
[How to store templated objects of different type in container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601676/how-to-store-templated-objects-of-different-type-in-container)