# What is the best way to keep a pointer to different types when only one of them is needed at a time?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unions, void-pointers

I'm in a situation where I need to have a pointer to an object of unknown type as a member of another class.
But the list of valid object types are known at compile-time.

Say I have:

```
// A class templated on T
template<class T> class obj;

// Now assume there are some objects of types obj<...> somewhere else
obj<int> obj1;
obj<double> obj2;

// Now, manager needs to create a pointer for these objects
// in a specific manner at construction-time

// Say, we have to choose a canonical object (and set the other as secondary)

// manager shouldn't be templated on T because It needs
// to have multiple members of type obj<...>
template<class R>
class manager
{
    shared_ptr<...> canObjPtr;
    shared_ptr<...> secObjPtr;
 public:   
    // once set, canonical obj is not expected to change
    explicit manager(string canonicalObj);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Some initial thoughts that don't really work:

1. The most promising approach I can think of is to add T1 and T2 template arguments to manager and construct like this: `manager<R, obj<int>, obj<double>>()`. I get the feeling that I should grab the "canonicalObj" string with a static function before manager construction and then decide on which manager to create `manager<R, obj<int>, obj<double>>` or `manager<R, obj<double>, obj<int>>`.
2. How about "templating" manager on `obj1 and obj2` objects directly. Does it seem feasible? Note that I'm resilient to adding template parameters to manager because it's involved in some RunTime selection mechanism that doesn't like working multi-param templates.
3. Instead of 2 member pointers, create 4 (See below, but this is lousy and will surely drive me crazy in the implementation: Need to always check if one pointer is null before using either of them)

```
template<class R> manager
{
    sharedPtr<obj<int>> canObjPtrI;
    sharedPtr<obj<float>> canObjPtrF;

    // same for secObjPtr above
 public:
    explicit manager(string canonicalObj);
}
```

4. `std::any and std::variant` (and their boost equivalents) are out of the question because I want to keep using c++11 and can't use boost by policy. If I were to break one of the rules I would consider upgrading to c++17.
5. I don't think the use of `shared_ptr<void>` for example can give any benefits because I would have to cast the pointer to the correct type anyway and can't use the interface of the object from the void pointer.
6. The same can be said for `union`. It provides little to no improvement over 3.

Also, if you see this as a potential design problem, please don't hold back. I invite you to point out any flaws/improvements you notice.

[Edit] **What this code is trying to do is ...**

Basically, I need to choose a canonical and secondary objects just like I explained above from a list of pre-constructed `obj<int> and obj<double>` objects:

Based on user-input the class should decide on a canonical object and perform calculations based on this decision. I already have facilities to get references to these objects by their name (string). The only problem is that their types are different and making them inherit from a base class would constraint me to use the interface of that base only (is this correct?).

### A minimal example as requested in comments

```
// A base template for objects defines common
// and possibly different interface.
template<class T> class objBase
{
protected:
    field<T> f_;

public:

    // Public data type
    using fieldType = field<T>;

    // New selects from "Registered childs of objBase"
    // at runtime
    static shared_ptr<objBase>::New() const;

    // Pure virtual to update the obj
    virtual void update() = 0;

    // Const-Access to field
    const field<T>& getField() const;
};

// Created objects are also registered automatically to a database
// i.e. I can get (const-)refs to them by querying the database
shared_ptr<objBase<int>> obj1 = objBase<int>::New();
shared_ptr<objBase<int>> obj2 = objBase<int>::New();
shared_ptr<objBase<float>> obj3 = objBase<float>::New();

// In manager, something like this needs to happen
template<class R>
class manager
{
private:
    // Read 2 target obj names from user input
    pair<string,string> objNames;

    // Possible types for requested objs:
    // obj_a, obj_b : both objBase<int> or both objBase<float>
    // or they can have different types 
    // But we essentially need only:
    pointer<...> canonicalObj;
    pointer<...> secondaryObj;

    // These should be used like this
    void useObjField() const
    {
        // Not using auto for clarity
        const decltype(*canonicalObj)::FieldType& objField
            = canonicalObj->getField();
        for(int i=0; i < objField.size(); ++i)
        {
            // Loop through elements and use them for some calculations
            // Related to other fields in manager
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I would say a small wrapper class with a `.get()` or `operator*()` should suffice. Let the wrapper handle the logic. And `shared_ptr` is absolutely wrong for this.

Comment: _I'm in a situation where I need to have a pointer to an object of unknown type as a member of another class. But the list of valid object types are known at compile-time._ `std::variant` is really the first which came in my mind.

Comment: @Scheff Yep, but shouldn't use C++17

Comment: The other option might be to derive the template class `obj<>` from a class (say `obj_base`) so that you can handle instances by a pointer (or reference) to `obj_base`. Though, this might introduce runtime polymorphy while `std::variant` keeps it at compile time.

Comment: Your question has to much focus on your solution (pointer to some set of types) instead on problem you are trying to solve. If you could describe what kind of problem this code solve we could provide solution which fits better to that problem. Now we can just approve or criticize your approach.

Comment: @sweenish Wrap ```obj```? Could you please clarify?

Comment: You can implement a "just good enough" `std::variant` yourself for your particular use case.

Comment: OK you have a pointer to some object of an unknown type. What are you planning to do with it?

Comment: use the interface of the pointed-to object. It wouldn't be a problem if I were to only pass the pointer around :)

Comment: Implementing my own ```variant``` is now my last resort, thanks for the idea

Comment: _"Based on user-input the class should decide on a canonical object and perform calculations based on this decision."_ — It really sounds like a problem suitable for runtime/dynamic polymorphism. What's wrong with inheriting `obj<T>` from some common base?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, It is, but manager is templated on many other things and I rely on runtime polymorphism for most of the selections but was hoping to do this without that. Mainly because it's not the actual use who chooses the canonical object but some other class.

Comment: @DanielLangr obj<T> has T-dependent interface that must be used in manager. This can happen only if manager is templated on T or if I have a fully qualified pointer to obj, is that right?

Comment: @Elwardi So you have objects of different types (with different API) and you want to use one of them in a manager based on some runtime condition, right? Then, you always must resolve some switch anytime you want to access that object (to resolve the actual type and it's API). In such a case, I would use just a plain old `union` and store the raw pointer inside. It's definitely not a good idea to use `shared_ptr` together with stack-allocated objects.

Comment: @DanielLangr OK, but what type the pointer has to have? obj1 and obj2 are not necessarily stack-allocated. I just declare them this way here for reference. is this misleading?

Comment: @Elwardi Pointer to the type of the objects. Something as `union { obj<int>* p_int; obj<float>* p_float; };`. And then, you will use a particular `p_xxx` according to the runtime condition.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, this is definitely an option. But is there any benefit over the 3rd approach I mentioned? Testing for member validity every time will be painful and will result in a degraded API. I'm considering wrapping this idea in a variant-like class.

Comment: @Elwardi I guess we are not able to compare different approaches until you show us how you want to use the pointed-to objects inside the manager class and how the interface of these objects differ from each other. At least some minimal example would be very helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220850/discussion-between-elwardi-and-daniel-langr).

Comment: What kind of interface?  If you have a base class that sets the interface for derived classes to implement, then you don't have to do anything special, just keep a pointer to the base class. Otherwise, an unknown type has an unknown interface. How are you planning to use it?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/FoamScience/f43acc677fe4eda87db4a8fc35e51bf4) for a typical use of such interface. Although after playing around with std::variant, I think I'll just go with `manager<R, T1, T2>`

Comment: So you don't have an unknown type. You have a tagged union. Each arm of the union has its own interface. There is no "*the* interface of the pointed-to object", there are several unrelated interfaces. You may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686677).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Exactly, thanks for the link but unfortunately, access to the union members will happen repeatedly (not a one-time call) so a switch (or try-n-catch) will not help. But `std::visit` is something new to me and potentially very helpful. I decided to stick with manager<R, T1, T2> and make it a convention that T1 should be the type of the canonical object.

Answer (score 1):

> `std::any` and `std::variant` (and their boost equivalents) are out of the question because I want to keep using c++11 and can't use boost by policy.

Still not a problem: You can use [`mpark::variant`](https://github.com/mpark/variant) - it's C++11-compatible. There are also other such variant class implementations floating around. If you'd rather go with an `any`-like class (less recommended), try perhaps [`linb::any`](https://github.com/thelink2012/any) - same idea; C++11-compatible.

IIANM, these are both header-only library (ignore the test/example programs), so you don't even need any complex installation; you can just grab a recent version of the header, or be super-organized, build and install them properly with CMake, then use a CMake `find_package()` command to locate them.

Finally, a "qualified union" would be a rough alternative to using a variant. A variant is essentially a union and a variable which tells you which of the types in the union is the active one. I would not recommend this, for simplicity of use and safety - but it would likely mean a lot less code.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about mpark, but did know about linb and some other libraries that try to bring c++14+ features to c++11. I try not to use those, but as I said in a previous comment, implementing my own "variant" is my last resort.